# Need advice for live camera feed

Tags: camera

I'm helping with the AV for a veterans day event in a few weeks. Because of the cramped space, the people on stage will be facing the front of a gymnasium and the audience will be on bleachers on both sides. This means that without a live camera feed, the audience will only be seeing the sides of people not the front. There will be veterans on stage, so it is imperative that people see what is going on. The plan is to have projectors on both sides with a live camera feed. Would the rpi-cam-web-interface on a Pi 4 work as a way to get this live camera feed? I have not purchased the camera yet so unfortunately I can't try this on my own. For clarification, there will be laptops connected to the projectors and the laptops and the Pi will be connected to WiFi. We don't have any other camera equipment that would be suitable.

Comment: Should work. Main issue will be how good is the Wi-Fi? What speed? How many devices connected?

Comment: Just the laptops and the pi will be connected and a pi zero w will be used as the AP. It would be possible to run everything via Ethernet to an unmanaged Ethernet switch. Would all of the devices still have IP addresses then? And if not, how could I get the devices IPs?

Comment: Ethernet would be more reliable. You would either need to use static ip addresses or use something to give ip addresses to the devices (router or dhcp server).

Comment: Ok, will be using Ethernet then. Thanks for your help!